# Automatically open a task pane in Outlook web add-in if a user is starting to read a flagged email

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

We are starting to develop a add-in for Outlook which should start/show when a user reads a mail item which was flagged before.
The wish to autostart seams to be very old. I have found similarly question starting three years ago.
Maybe somebody has an idea for a workaround.

Comment: Thank you Eugene, I am a little bit frustrated, that there is no way to open a task pane if a item is opened. We have decided to let the user open with a ribbon button and then stay open.

Comment: HOV thanks for the feedback, the current workaround would be what Eugene suggested to use something like pinning. The feature to open task pane automatically when opening an item is not a part of the current product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page: https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to start a task pane automatically (programmatically) in web add-ins. Your choices are:

1. Pin the pane and track the selected items and update the pane accordingly. See [Implement a pinnable task pane in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/pinnable-taskpane) for more information about that.
2. Use the ribbon button to open a task pane. This is a default action for the ribbon button.
3. Use the notification action to open a task pane. This is a new feature.